# Elements in the word each add class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Normal HTML output;

```
<p><h1>Big title</h1>
foo bar foo bar foo bar</p>
```

I want like this;

```
<p>
<h1>
<div class="someCls">Big</div>
<div class="someCls">Title</div>
</h1>
<div class="someCls">foo</div> 
<div class="someCls">bar</div> 
<div class="someCls">foo</div> 
<div class="someCls">bar</div> 
<div class="someCls">foo</div> 
<div class="someCls">bar</div>
</p>
```

I couldn't create the thereof logic with jquery & javascript.
Can you help me?

Comment: `p` can't have div as a child

Comment: doesn't matter 'div' can be 'span' or other element.

Comment: `Elements in the word each add class?` is meaningless , please clarify

Comment: Assign `someCls` class to all words in the writings inside the elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup has a problem as `p` can't have block elements as its descendants so

```js
$('div').contents().contents().addBack().each(function() {
  if (this.nodeType == 3) {
    $(this).replaceWith($(this.nodeValue.replace(/([^\s]+)/g, '<div class="somecalss">$1</div>')))
  }
})
```

```css
.somecalss {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1>Big title</h1>
  foo bar foo bar foo bar
</div>
```